# Python: Element-wise implementation of 'in' conditional operator

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, elementwise-operations

So, I have two lists:

```
x =[170 169 168 167 166 165 183 201 219 237 255 274 293 312 331 350]
y =[201,168]
```

I want to write a conditional `if` statement that is true only if all the contents of `y` are in `x`. How do I do this?

E.g. -- `assert(y[0] in x)` and `assert(y[a] in x)` both give `True`, but `assert(y in x)` gives `False`. Similarly, `assert( any(y) in x )` raises an error as well.

Comment: Why are you using `assert` like that? `assert` should be used to check the validity of your code's logic, not for validating data.

Comment: BTW, is `x` actually a plain Python list? It looks like it could be a Numpy array, in which case you should be using Numpy functions or methods with it.

Comment: @PM2Ring Could you please elucidate on your first comment? I agree with the second.

Comment: Assertions are used to test for things which should _never_ happen. If the assertion gets raised that means your program logic is wrong and needs to be changed. See [When to use assert](http://archive.is/5GfiG#selection-9.0-9.18)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sets](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) are better for this:

```
set(y) <= set(x)
```

Note that this relies on your list contents being immutable, as mutable (or, more specifically, *unhashable*) objects cannot be members of sets. As in this case, lists of integers are fine.

Answer (score 1):

`all(e in x for e in y)`

Similarly, you can use

`any(e in x for e in y)`

To see if any elements in `y` are in `x`.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on having them be lists, you can use the `all()` function:

```
all(item in x for item in y)
```